# How to fill Matplotlib Rectangle patch with .png image

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to add a `patches.Rectangle()` element with a .png image fill. Any help would be much appreciated.

Current attempt to simply overlay an image over the rectangle of the same size:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.hatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon, Rectangle
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from PIL import Image
from resizeimage import resizeimage

img =Image.open('gravel_or_conglomerate_1.png')
l=400
w=300
img = resizeimage.resize_contain(img, [w, l])
im = np.array(img, dtype=np.uint8)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.add_patch(Rectangle((0,50), l, w,facecolor='blue', edgecolor='k',   linewidth=0,alpha=1))
ax.imshow(im)
ax.axis('off')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short slightly modified example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.hatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon, Rectangle
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from PIL import Image

l=400
w=300
img =Image.open('GUDBOI.png').resize((l, w))
im = np.asarray(img)
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
rect = Rectangle((0, 0), l, w,facecolor='blue', edgecolor='k',
                       linewidth=3,alpha=1, transform = ax.transData)
im = ax.imshow(im)
im.set_clip_path(rect)
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

The main issue is that you were not clipping the image to the patch. Also that you added the patch to the axes.[image: Example with an image I had]

More on https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_clip_path.html

Comment: Thanks! That works well. Is there any way to have the background of the .png removed so that the background colour shows through with the black components of the .png remaining?

Comment: You mean as in the picture I sent where the planet has had it's background selectively removed? Or do you mean to have everything but the picture on the patch a certain color? If you want everything but the picture to change color you must do so by changing the color of the figure through `fig.set_facecolor("")`. This is because the axes can't have it's color changed after calling `ax.axis("off")`.

Comment: My goal is to have a rectangle patch that retains a given colour, with a second rectangle that has the .png pattern over top of it. This would yield a box similar to this (<https://www.google.com/search?q=strat+column&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk033O3f8mEU38TSR8d8HQdJ17jxwMQ:1592518751349&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjakuPTsozqAhUYr54KHZ02BgUQ_AUoAXoECBEQAw&biw=1368&bih=808#imgrc=aC4YDA6OUC4vgM>)

Comment: I am not sure if this is the best way to do it but you can always add new patches to the background or front. To control for which patches go on top or below, make use of the `zorder` parameter. The higher the `zorder`, the more on top the patch will be. I hope this answers your question.